# PostgreSQL comparar hora entre duas horas, e se ultrapassar as horas do dia, limitar até 23:59

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, query, datetime

Estou fazendo um `query` `sql` no `ruby-on-rails` pelo `PostgreSQL` onde verifico se a entrada do usuário está entre `hora_entrada` e `hora_entrada + (hora_entrada + limite_banco_horas)` e o mesmo faço para `hora_fim`, em um determinado `dia`. Porém se a `hora_fim + limite_banco_horas` ultrapassar as horas daquele dia, o filtro já não trás as `pessoas` do dia informado. Preciso limitar a comparação até até `23:59`, caso a `soma com limite_banco_horas` ultrapasse este valor, 23:59.
Exemplo:

```
SELECT "dias_trabalhados".* 
FROM "dias_trabalhados" 
INNER JOIN "presencas" ON "presencas"."id" = "dias_trabalhados"."presenca_id"
INNER JOIN "jornada_trabalhos" ON "jornada_trabalhos"."id" = "dias_trabalhados"."jornada_trabalho_id" 
LEFT JOIN "pessoas" ON "pessoas"."id" = "presencas"."pessoa_id"                 
LEFT JOIN "liberacao_bancos_hora" ON "liberacao_bancos_hora"."pessoa_id" = "pessoas"."id" AND "liberacao_bancos_hora"."data" = '2017-09-22' 

WHERE "presencas"."ano" = 2017 
AND "presencas"."mes" = 9 AND "dias_trabalhados"."dia" = 22 
AND (

     (
        "liberacao_bancos_hora"."limite" IS NOT NULL

        AND (

            OR (
                ("jornada_trabalhos"."hora_entrada" - ("liberacao_bancos_hora"."limite" ||' hours')::interval) >= '20:00'
                AND "jornada_trabalhos"."hora_entrada" <= '20:00'
            )

            OR (
                "jornada_trabalhos"."hora_saida" >= '22:00'
                AND ("jornada_trabalhos"."hora_saida" + ("liberacao_bancos_hora"."limite" ||' hours')::interval) <= '22:00'
            )
        )
     )
))
```

Neste exemplo, minha query verifica na tabela `dias_trabalhados` todas as `pessoas` que possuem `limite_bancos_horas` cadastrado, no dia `22/09/2017`, entre `20:00` e `22:00`.
Suponhamos que `hora_saida` de uma `pessoa` seja `19:00`, e ela tem `7h` de `banco de horas` e poderá bater ponto até 01:00 do dia 23/09/2017.

E então preciso limitar meu filtro na minha query para que se a `(hora_saida + limite_bancos_hora)` ultrapassar das 23:59, eu coloque o horário de comparação até às `23:59`.

No `PostgreSQL` existe uma função para isso, ou como faço para limitar até o fim do dia?

Comment: Percebi que sua consulta possui uma cláusula `WHERE` dentro da condição `ON` do `LEFT JOIN` com a tabela `liberacao_bancos_hora`. Sua consulta está correta ?

Comment: está funcionando, perdão, foi na hora de indexar aqui na edição do texto, vou arrumar, obrigado!

Comment: Eu entendi o seu problema! Porém, para que eu possa elaborar uma resposta mais adequada ao seu caso, seria interessante que você incluisse na sua pergunta a estrutura das tabelas que fazem parte da sua consulta. É possível ?